# C# Reading particular values in a string

Tags: c#, stringreader

I have the following line from a string:

`colors numResults="100" totalResults="6806926"`

I want to extract the value `6806926` from the above string
How is it possible?

So far, I have used StringReader to read the entire string line by line.
Then what should I do?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Which line from a XML file?

Comment: The statement is missing.

Comment: `totalResults` is an attribute. [System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.aspx) might interest you.

Comment: If you always want to find the value of the attribute `totalResults`and that attribute isn't used elsewhere in the string you could use a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to get it.

Comment: If you need the only value from whole xml file, just use simple regex; otherwise you should look at xml nodes traversing technique instead of read file with stringreader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the this is in Mytext of string type variable

now

```
Mytext.Substring(Mytext.indexof("totalResults="),7);
```

//the function indexof will return the point wheres the value start, 
//and 7 is a length of charactors that you want to extract

I am using similar of this ........

Comment: Well, you could also just `return 6806926;` (sarcasm). I think it's safe to assume that the value of `totalResults` will vary and that it will not always be exactly 7 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's also a regex, but this `string` approach should work also:

```
string xmlLine = "[<colors numResults=\"100\" totalResults=\"6806926\">]";
string pattern = "totalResults=\"";
int startIndex = xmlLine.IndexOf(pattern);
if(startIndex >= 0)
{
    startIndex += pattern.Length;
    int endIndex = xmlLine.IndexOf("\"", startIndex); 
    if(endIndex >= 0)
    {
        string token = xmlLine.Substring(startIndex,endIndex - startIndex);
        // if you want to calculate with it
        int totalResults = int.Parse( token );
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/nKbsAd)

Answer (score 0):

You can read with Linq2Xml, numResults and totalResults are *Attributes*, and `<colors numResults="100" totalResults="6806926">` is *Element*, so you can simply get it by n`myXmlElement.Attributes("totalResults")`.

Answer (score 0):

This function will split the string into a list of key value pairs which you can then pull out whatever you require

```
        static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>  getItems(string s)
    {
        var retVal = new List<KeyValuePair<String, string>>();

        var items = s.Split(' ');

        foreach (var item in items.Where(x => x.Contains("=")))
        {
            retVal.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>( item.Split('=')[0], item.Split('=')[1].Replace("\"", "") ));
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
string input = "colors numResults=\"100\" totalResults=\"6806926\"";
string pattern = "totalResults=\"(?<results>\\d+?)\"";
Match result = new Regex(pattern).Match(input);
Console.WriteLine(result.Groups["results"]);
```

Be sure to have this included:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```